# Installing php-fpm over php version missmatched

Tags: php, centos, yum, php-fpm, installation

I have PHP installed by yum from the base @updates repository on Centos 6.3:

```
 php x86_64 5.3.3-14.el6_3 @updates 3.5 M
```

I would like to install php-fpm version 5.3 because our web software works only under php version 5.3.

Unfortunatelly:

```
yum install php-fpm
```

offer me to install verion 5.4.10-1.el6.remi from remi repository with full Updating for dependencies of my base php to version 5.4.10-1.el6:

```
Installing:
php-fpm x86_64 5.4.10-1.el6.remi remi 1.3 M
Updating for dependencies:
php x86_64 5.4.10-1.el6.remi remi 2.7 M
... other php-* files
```

My question is: What is the method can be to install php-fpm exactly version 5.3 from the reposiroty? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no php-fpm in the CentOS repository.
You have the CentOS provided php 5.3.3-14 installed.

You are trying to install php-fpm from the remi repository, which will have a dependency on php-common from remi again.
Even if you get the php-fpm 5.3.x remi RPM from their archive it will conflict with the already installed php-common from CentOS.

Either way, if you want php-fpm your currently installed php needs to change.
You could replace your CentOS php 5.3.3 with a remi php 5.3.3.
The usage of conflicting package names is the reasons why I dislike the remi repository so much - unlike for example the ius repository.

Answer (score 0):

REMI's archived old rpms can be ONLY installed manually from:

```
http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/olds/x86_64/
```

Example:

```
rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/olds/x86_64/php-5.3.19-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
```